# Как отключить активацию меню при нажатии на alt в vs community?

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

Скачал vs community для изучения C++, и заметил что при нажатии на кнопку `Alt` выделяется кнопка "Меню" в верхней панели. Это доставляет большой дискомфорт при попытке сменить язык комбинацией клавиш `Shift + Alt`.

Можно ли как то отключить это выделение?